# Python Json with returns AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, attributeerror

Why does this return AttributeError: __enter__

Sorting method is just a string created based on how the list is sorted, and current time uses stfttime

```
current_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", gmtime())

filename = f"Komplett-{str(sorting_method)}-{str(current_time)}.txt"
if not os.path.exists(f'C:/Users/tagp/OneDrive/Dokumenter/Python/{filename}'):
        open(str(filename), "w+")   
with (filename, "w+") as json_data:
            my_list = {}
            my_list["products"] = []
            for thing in my_products:
                my_list["products"].append({
                    "Product Title":thing.title,
                    "Price":thing.price,
                    "Rating":thing.rating,
                    "Stock":thing.stock
                    })
            json.dump(my_list, json_data, indent = 4)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "komplett.py", line 172, in <module>
        with (filename, "w") as json_data:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: can you post the complete traceback

Comment: Edited post with full traceback

Comment: You forgot the `open`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just for got to use open

```
current_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", gmtime())

filename = f"Komplett-{str(sorting_method)}-{str(current_time)}.txt"
if not os.path.exists(f'C:/Users/tagp/OneDrive/Dokumenter/Python/{filename}'):
        open(str(filename), "w+")   
with open(filename, "w+") as json_data:
            my_list = {}
            my_list["products"] = []
            for thing in my_products:
                my_list["products"].append({
                    "Product Title":thing.title,
                    "Price":thing.price,
                    "Rating":thing.rating,
                    "Stock":thing.stock
                    })
            json.dump(my_list, json_data, indent = 4)
```

Comment: Welcome, and also dont forget to post the traceback when posting a question. it will be easier for the community peers to solve the query

Comment: I figured it might have been somewhat easy to understand what it was about, given how short it was.  My mistake though will remember that for next time