# How to fix “AttributeError: __enter__” when using csv.reader(open(..)..)?

Tags: python, csv, with-statement

I get the following error with my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\XXX\Sentiment Analysis-vader.py", line 34, in <module>
    f.printer()

File "C:\Users\XXX\Sentiment Analysis-vader.py", line 18, in printer
    with csv.reader(open('analyse_' + str(bloombergcode) + '.csv', 'r'), delimiter= ",",quotechar='|') as q2:

AttributeError: __enter__

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I used the following code:

```
import csv
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

class VaderSentiment:
    def __init__(self, bloomcode):
        self.bloomcode = bloomcode

    def print_sentiment_scores(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
        snt = analyser.polarity_scores(self.sentence)
        print("{:-<40} {}".format(self.sentence, str(snt)))

    def printer(self):
        bloombergcode = self.bloomcode
        with csv.reader(open('analyse_' + str(bloombergcode) + '.csv', 'r'), delimiter= ",",quotechar='|') as q2:
            for line in q2:
                for field in line:
                    print_sentiment_scores(field)

for code in ('AAPL', 'NFLX'):
    f = VaderSentiment(code)
    f.printer()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I already saw some other similar problems ([Python Json with returns AttributeError: __enter__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273154/python-json-with-returns-attributeerror-enter)) but the solutions do not work on my problem.

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) correctly. It does not support being placed inside a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Try to do it the same way as in the [usage example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
with open('analyse_' + str(bloombergcode) + '.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    q2 = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for line in q2:
        # ..rest of your code..
```

Wrap [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) instead inside the `with` (because `open` supports it and is actually the recommended way of using it) then use `csv.reader` inside it.